# Div takes the place of another div when I zoom in

Tags: css, html, zooming

I am new to HTML and CSS. I have started to make my own website, I have encountered a problem, **it's that when I zoom in the content `div` goes into the menu `div`**. I can't seem to find the answer by myself so it would great if you could help me.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="logoBar">   
            <div class="helper">        
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="vmenu"> 
                <ul> 
                  <li><a href="">Acceuil</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Identification</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Mon Parcours</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Ma Formation</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Mes Projets</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Dossier de Veille</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="">Contact Me</a></li> 
                </ul>   
            </div> 

            <div class="content">
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/******************Custom Styles********************/
 @font-face
{
font-family: stainy;
src: url(../font/stainy.ttf);
}

body{
    background:url(../img/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.logoBar{ 
    background:url(../img/LogoBar.png) ;
    height:149px;   
    position:relative;
    width: 100%; min-width: 960px;
}

.helper{
    height:120px;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}

.logo{  
    background:url(../img/Untitled-1.png) no-repeat center;
     width:262px;
     height:80px;
     margin:0 auto;
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
}




div#vmenu { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .25em 0em .25em 0em; 
   /***border: solid 2px #30c9e0;***/   
   width: 13.5em; 
   float:left;


} 
div#vmenu ul { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   list-style: none;


} 

div#vmenu ul li { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   list-style: none; 
   color: #6F8083;
   font-family: stainy;
} 

div#vmenu ul a:link { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .2em 0em .2em .4em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-size:23pt;   
   color: #6F8083;
   font-family:stainy;

   display: block; 

} 

div#vmenu ul a:active { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .25em .5em .25em .5em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: black;
   font-family: stainy; 
   font-size:23pt;



} 

div#vmenu ul a:visited { 
   margin: 0; 
   color: #6F8083;
   font-family: stainy;
   text-decoration: none;  
   font-size:23pt;    
   color: #ffffff; 

} 

div#vmenu ul li a:hover { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .2em 0em .2em .4em; 
   text-decoration: none;  
   font-size:24pt;
   background-color: #30c9e0; 
   color: black; 

} 


.content{

  width: 700px ;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  border: 1px solid #30c9e0;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #4D4F50;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #4D4F50;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #4D4F50;

}
```

Comment: Is this your code? http://jsfiddle.net/7J4At/  Or at least update it to solve your problem.

Comment: when you zoom in the browser? or when use the CSS zoom property?

Comment: it's when i zoom in the browser

Comment: try using box-sizing: border-box in your css code, like this: `*,*:after,*:before{box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;} `and check your css too, avoid use display:table, and table-cell to make your layout.

Comment: I don't really understand what I should change, and can you explain why I shouldn't use display:table? I use it to center the logo horizontally and vertically.

Comment: you are learning yet, better use a solution to positioning your elements using grids, check it http://960.gs/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're looking for, without modifying the layout you've created, you could add a `min-width` to your `body` style. (for your layout, 1150px ought to do it, but that is a weirdly irregular minimum width for any device. just FYI.)

Comment: Without sounding too much like Yoda, there is no good or bad, it depends entirely on your desired output. Having said that... If, for example, your desired output requires a 1920x1080 screen resolution to be seen in its entirety, the number of users able to see it will be more limited than if it required only a 1024x768 resolution. Make sense?

Comment: yes it makes sense, I want the website to be viewed correctly in all the resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain divs % like this

```
div#vmenu { 
margin: 0; 
padding: .25em 0em .25em 0em;  
width: 20%; 
float:left;
background:#036;


}   
.contentWaper{ width:79%; float:left;}
.content{

width: 700px ;
height:100px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
border: 1px solid #30c9e0;
background-color:#000;
text-align:center;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #4D4F50;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #4D4F50;
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #4D4F50;

}
```

`<div class="contentWaper">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
</div>`

Comment: But if I use float:left the box is not centered and it goes down the menu when I zoom in

Comment: you have maintain widths in percentages (%)

Comment: Could you explain how to maintain widths in % please?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is Added one more div to wrap `.content`

and give `margin-left: 14em` to wrapped div

[Here is the demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/anojI/)